# How to Correct Incorrect Birth Year in My FIDE Profile?

Tags: fide, rating, tournament

I recently discovered that my FIDE (International Chess Federation) profile lists an incorrect birth year. My actual rating from years ago was 1450, but the birth year on the site is wrong.

Here's my profile: [FIDE Profile](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/42582245/chart).

Could anyone guide me on correcting this error on the FIDE website? Are there specific steps or contacts at FIDE that I should follow to update my personal information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can contact them on email, here are their contacts: https://fide.com/contacts

Comment: Unfortunately, I got no answer to my email.